# Why doesn't the replace method in pandas for a subset of columns work with inplace=True option?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following data

```
d = {'color' : pd.Series(['white', 'blue', 'orange']), 
    'second_color': pd.Series(['white', 'black', 'blue']),
    'value' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3.])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Now suppose I want to replace 'white' in columns color and second_color with NaN , in place. I know that one way to do this is

```
df = df.replace('white', np.NaN)

    color   second_color  value
0   NaN     NaN           1.0
1   blue    black         2.0
2   orange  blue          3.0
```

But why is it that when I try

```
df[['color', 'second_color']].replace('white', np.NaN, inplace=True)
```

instead I don't get the desired results? That is, 'white' doesn't get replaced in df.

Comment: `df[['color', 'second_color']]` is not the original dataframe. It is a slice of it. You modify the slice, but the original is not changed.

Comment: Ah that makes sense--thanks @DYZ.

Comment: :-) More information: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9106

Comment: Dupe explores the same concept.